# Difference between i386 and x86-64 memory stack

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

While trying to make a very tiny program with NASM and GCC on my Ubuntu machine, I noticed something weird.

The following code compiles fine under 64-bit NASM and GCC:

```
   global  main
   extern  puts

section .text
   main:
     push    rax
     mov rdi, message
     call puts
     jmp exit
  exit:
    ;return stack memory
    pop rax
    ret
  message:
    db "Hello from NASM!", 0
```

But when trying to compile the same code (only with registers changed) under 32-bit NASM and GCC, it will either result segmentation fault and/or random characters. Why is this happening? Does the x64 architecture have different way in storing memory to the stack than i386? If so, how could this behaviour be prevented?

Comment: The calling conventions are different, aren't they?

Comment: Maybe use a debugger and find out where the fault is occurring?

Comment: Unless they have changed the whole language specification last week, this is not C, but assembly language. Don't spam tags! (calling library functions does not change this!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in 32-bit mode, *most* calling conventions (`cdecl`, `stdcall`, etc...) expect arguments to be pushed on the stack, not in registers, unlike in 64-bit mode, and also, you would need to adjust the stack pointer after calling `puts`, so you would need to do something like:

```
lea edx, @message
push edx
call puts
add esp, 4
```

For the program to produce the same output in 32-bit mode.  I may not have the NASM syntax right as I usually write assembly code in MASM and GAS.

Comment: So that was the problem, thanks! Haven't really done with i386 for a while

Comment: It doesn't really matter what *most* calling conventions require. This is a C standard library function, so it's going to use the cdecl calling convention, which means that your answer is correct. (If it was stdcall, then the callee would clean the stack, not the caller!)

Comment: @CodyGray Agreed for sure, but I was trying to give a general-case answer - if, say, he was calling a function that used ms fastcall instead of a standard C function, then it would be correct to have first argument in ECX